# change value in imported file, use new value in script

Tags: javascript, node.js, config, fs

How can I change a value in a imported json file and use that newly changed value in the script?
this is what I have that I am trying to use but it will make me restart the program before the value is actually counted as what it was changed too.

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()
const exit = require('exit')
var config = require('.\\config.json')
const debug = config['debug']
const fs = require('fs-extra')


function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
}
// if (debug == "true") {console.log()}
if (debug == "true") {
    var debug_on = prompt("debug mode is on, would you like to turn it off? ")
    if (debug_on == "yes") {
        console.log("debug has been disabled")
        require('child_process').execSync('node config_setter.js --debug=false')
    }
    if (debug_on == "no") {
        console.log("debug will stay enabled")
    }
}

if (config['experimental-asked'] == "false") {
    var exp_clean = prompt("do you want to try experimental cleaning? ")
    if (exp_clean == "yes") {
        require('child_process').execSync('node config_setter.js --clean=true --asked=true')
    }
    if (exp_clean == "no") {
        console.log("as you wish")
        require('child_process').execSync('node config_setter.js --clean=false --asked=true')
    }
    if (exp_clean == "debug") {
        console.log("debug enabled, this enables cleaning also")
        require('child_process').execSync('node config_setter.js --clean=true --asked=true --debug=true')
    }  
}
```

```
if (debug_arg !== undefined) {
        if (exp_asked !== undefined) {
            config['experimental-cleaning'] = exp_clean
            config['experimental-asked'] = exp_asked
            config['debug'] = debug_arg
            config_string = JSON.stringify(config, null, 4)
            fs.writeFile(config_dir, config_string, (err) => {
                if (err) {console.log("error"), err}
            })
            exit
        }
}
```

Comment: Which value?  How about experimenting with just the few lines that import, log, change and then log again?  Post that here?

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac, Windows etc?

Comment: Im on windows, im trying to change config['experimental-cleaning']

Comment: On windows the syntax should be `var config = require("./config")`

Answer (score 0):

You're currently reading in the file as a String

`var config = require('.\\config.json')`

You need to convert it to JSON in order to use it according to your second snippet:

```
var config = require('.\\config.json');
var configJSON = JSON.parse(config);
```

Comment: im calling the second snippet and changing the values with it while the first snippet goes to another chunk after the second process exits so i can use the new value of true in an if statement inside of the first snippet, false, 1> 2, true > new if (var == true) {}

Comment: also the second snippet gets config the same way const config = require('.\\config.json')

Comment: @Fisheiyy I understand, you'll still need to parse the config file in that case.